# Ubuntu 23.04 AMD RX7600 Steam and proton issues?

Tags: games, steam, intel, radeon, 23.04

I am using a new system:

- i5 Raptor lake,
- 8GB AMD RX 7600,
- DDR5 32GB
- on Ubuntu 23.04 Lunar Lobster.

The GPU is on MESA driver, the RX 7600 only came out a month ago.
On trying my games in Steam there are graphic glitches, one game won't start and another says no Internet connection even though Steam itself is connected (150mb fibre connection).

My last PC was a

- Skylake i5,
- NVidia 950GTX
- on 22.04

and had none of these issues.
I'm wondering if the new raptor lake CPU and AMD Radeon RX 7600 are causing the issue.

Should I just wait a while and hope proton (I have tried different versions), the Linux kernel and the drivers improve and the games on Steam start working OK? Or is there something I can do now?

Answer (score 0):

It was all down to proton versions. The hardware, raptor lake cpu and amd radeon all work perfectly. Its just trying different proton versions and seeing which one works best for each game.